# Swift - Move UItextField up when it is inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, keyboard, uitextfield

I am trying to move up `UITextField` when it is inside a `UITableViewCell` and the keyboard appears, but I don't have a `TableViewController`. The `UITableView` is inside a regular `ViewController`.

The code below works fine for `UITextFields` that are not inside a `UITableViewCell`. When I use it for `UITextFields` inside a `UITableViewCell` it doesn't work. The `UIScrollView` doesn't even move.

```
import UIKit

class CriarPerfilViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    //MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var fotoImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var perfilTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!


    //MARK: - Propriedades
    let nomeTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))

    //MARK: - Métodos reescritos da View
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

        //Define delegates
        perfilTableView.delegate = self
        perfilTableView.dataSource = self

        //Observers para ajuste de teclado
        let centralNotificacoes = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
        centralNotificacoes.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.ajusteParaTeclado(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        centralNotificacoes.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.ajusteParaTeclado(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Métodos da Table view data source
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let paddingView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10))

        if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {
            nomeTextField.frame.size = cell.frame.size
            nomeTextField.placeholder = "Name"

            nomeTextField.leftView = paddingView
            nomeTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always

            cell.addSubview(nomeTextField)
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        switch(section) {
            case 0: return "Exibition name"
            default: fatalError("Unknown section")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func tapGestureRecognizer(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    //MARK: - Métodos
    func ajusteParaTeclado(notificacao: NSNotification) {

        let informacoesDoUsuario = notificacao.userInfo!

        let tecladoFrameFinalTela = (informacoesDoUsuario[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
        let tecladoFrameFinalView = view.convertRect(tecladoFrameFinalTela, fromView: view.window)

        if notificacao.name == UIKeyboardWillHideNotification {
            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        } else {
            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: tecladoFrameFinalView.height + 10, right: 0)
        }

        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = scrollView.contentInset
    }
}
```

Comment: tableview already have a scrollview inside. so you cannot able to achieve by throwing notification and adjusting the position of uitextfield.you can be done by using scrollToIndexpath method, whenever textfield starts editing, get that textfield indexpath and scroll cell positon to  top or middle. it will help you i guess

Comment: I don't want to scroll inside the table, I need to scroll the `scrollView`outside the table. The tableView's scroll must stay put.